# Expo Push Notification not showing on lock screen

Tags: react-native, expo

I have been trying to create a push notification system for my little app but i ran into an issue. On my standalone app i only get push notifications on my top notification bar but not on lock screen. This is how my function that requires the expo token looks like:

```
registerForPushNotification = async () => {
    let { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS);
    if (status !== 'granted')
        return;
    let token = await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync();
    if (token)
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
            if (user) {
                firebase.database().ref(`/users/${user.uid}/token`).set({ value: token })
            } else {
                // User is signed out.
                // ...
            }
            // ...
        });
}
```

And this is the request i do in PostMan:
[image]

I correctly get the notification but not on my lock screen. Suggestions?

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I have the same question and can't seem to find it explained in the docs

Comment: Hi. This is not an issue with expo. This is an issue with the phone operating system or with the notifications permissions. Sorry for the late response